# Run startup file on shell restart in Idle

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm using Idle and Python 2.7 in Windows. I would like my startup file to run whenever I execute the Shell|Restart Shell command (Ctrl-F6).

I have edited idle.bat so that Idle always starts with the -s switch, running the startup file referenced in the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable when it starts. But that has no effect on subsequent restarts.

Is there some Idle preference that will automatically run the script on restarts? (I'm guessing no.)

If not, is there some line of code in somewhere in the idlelib folder that I could harmlessly change so that the -s switch would be invoked on restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no preference to set and no trivial code change.  The code change is tracker issue [5233](https://bugs.python.org/issue5233).  Adding a preference setting to not need -s is issue [5594](https://bugs.python.org/issue5594)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it seems you're the only one keeping those issues alive, so I suppose a resolution in the near future is unlikely.